# How can I use .count function correctly?

Tags: python, function, count, attributes

[image: image of code]

```
a=name11.count("t")+name11.count("r")+name11.count("u")+name11.count("e")
b=name21.count("l")+name21.count("o")+name21.count("v")+name21.count("e")
```

I can't see what's wrong here, but when I run the code it give attribute error.
I tried swapping lines and looked for typos but there is none I saw.

Comment: `name1.lower()` - you forgot to call the method

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

did you mean like this

```py
name11=name1.lower()#you should call the str.lower() function
name21=name2.lower()#it is better to use str()
a=name11.count("t")+name11.count("r")+name11.count("u")+name11.count("e")
b=name21.count("l")+name21.count("o")+name21.count("v")+name21.count("e")
```

full code

```py
print('welcome to the Love calculater')
name1=input('what is your name?\n')
name2=input('what is their name?\n')
name11=str(name1).lower()#you should call the str.lower() function
name21=str(name2).lower()#i used str() to handle if user input is integer
a=name11.count("t")+name11.count("r")+name11.count("u")+name11.count("e")
b=name21.count("l")+name21.count("o")+name21.count("v")+name21.count("e")
c=int(str(a)+str(b))
if c>40 and c<50:
    print(f"your score is {c}, you are alright together.")
elif c<10 and c>90:
    print(f"your score is {c}, you go together like coke and mentos.")
else:
    print(f"your score is {c}.")
```

you should call the function like `'string'.lower()` to work correctly
did this worked for you??

Comment: Code looks fine ,please consider adding some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

When you call a method/function without `()`, python don't call the actual method but it returns a function reference

in line number 8 & 9 you missed to call the method `lower()` but you assigned method reference of `str.lower` which means `name11` is not a `str` so the object don't have any method called `count()`

```
name  = "ABC".lower
print(name)
#op: <built-in method lower of str object at 0x7a1e3f1420>
print(name())
#op: abc
```

As you can see in this example `name` is actually a reference , however you can invoke the method by adding `()`